# Blockchain without cryptocurrency

Tags: blockchain, ether, cryptography

I am new to blockchain and am having certain doubts.

**Can we substitute cryptocurrency to carry out blockchain operations in any way ?**
Actually what i feel is that the volatility in cryptocurrencies and the hustle to create and manage crypto wallets is what makes layman stay away from using blockchain based solutions. If we use an alternative to cryptocurrencies then it could help simplify things further..
Requesting thoughts on the same.

Answer (score 1):

The capacity problem of blockchain is not dependend on a cryptocurrency.

It really does not matter what kind of permissioned or permissionless blockchain you have, if it becomes to the full capacity and cannot handle more tranactios there are only two options

1. Raise fees for those transactions that want higher priority
2. Drop transactions to make room for others

If you do fiat currency based pricing in this the case the price of the transaction would go up, not the price of the currency, so you are just shifting the problem around.

There are already Ethereum wallets that abstract ETH away from the user for the transaction fees and charge in a dollar. However they just need to charge more if the user wants to do the transaction in a busy network.